# Как заблокировать клавиатуру на Python?

Tags: python, клавиатура, поиск-библиотек

Нужна библиотека, которая работает примерно так:

```
import keyboardblocker
import time

keyboardblocker.block()
time.sleep(5)
keyboardblocker.unblock()
```

Comment: А что значит "блокировать клавиатуру"? Пока идет `sleep` только на Ctrl-C программа реагирует.

Comment: @AlexTitov это значит, что любое нажатие клавиш пользователем не будет считываться другими программами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил доработать свою реализацию:
Теперь можно зарегистрировать обработчики событий, а так же зарегистрировать условия для блокировки событий клавиатуры и мыши.

З.Ы. Это конечно некропост, но возможно мои изыскания кому-то да пригодятся, удачи)

```
print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<25} | __package__={2:<25}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
import ctypes
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui
import atexit
from collections import namedtuple
import threading
import time
import queue

class InputListener:
    """
    https://gist.github.com/Amgarak/5df8477bad67dabbc491322e74ce1c2c
    
    This class is designed for listening to keyboard and mouse events in a Windows environment. 
    It utilizes low-level hooks to capture events such as key presses, 
    key releases, mouse movements, and mouse button clicks. 
    The class provides functionalities to register event handlers and filters, 
    allowing custom processing of events. 
    It also supports the control of threads for concurrent event handling.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.flagRun=False
        self.signal = queue.Queue()
        
        self._key_down = set()
        
        self.if_handlers = set()
        self.handlers = set()
        
        self.listener_queues = {}
        self.listeners =[]

        self.event_types = {
                    win32con.WM_KEYDOWN: 'key_down', # 0x100: 'key down', - WM_KeyDown for normal keys - 256
                    win32con.WM_KEYUP: 'key_up', # 0x101: 'key up', - WM_KeyUp for normal keys - 257 
                    0x104: 'key_down',  # WM_SYSKEYDOWN, used for Alt key - 260
                    0x105: 'key_up'}  # WM_SYSKEYUP, used for Alt key - 261
        
        self.mouse_types={
                    0x200: 'move', # WM_MOUSEMOVE - 512 
                    0x20A: 'wheel', # WM_MOUSEWHEEL - 522 - scan_code_top: 7864320; scan_code_bot: 4287102976
                    0x20E: 'H_wheel', # WM_MOUSEHWHEEL - 526 
                    0x204: 'key_down', # WM_RBUTTONDOWN - 516
                    0x205: 'key_up', # WM_RBUTTONUP - 517
                    0x201: 'key_down', # WM_LBUTTONDOWN - 513
                    0x202: 'key_up', # WM_LBUTTONUP - 514
                    0x207: 'key_down', # WM_MBUTTONDOWN - 519
                    0x208: 'key_up', # WM_MBUTTONUP - 520
                    0x20B: 'key_down', # WM_XBUTTONDOWN - 523 - scan_code: 131072; scan_code: 65536
                    0x20C: 'key_up'} # WM_XBUTTONUP - 524 - scan_code: 131072; scan_code: 65536

        self.mouse_key={
                    0x200: 'move',  
                    0x20A: 'wheel', 
                    7864320: 'wheel_top', 
                    4287102976: 'wheel_bot', 
                    0x20E: 'H_wheel',  
                    0x204: 'right', 
                    0x205: 'right', 
                    0x201: 'left', 
                    0x202: 'left', 
                    0x207: 'middle', 
                    0x208: 'middle', 
                    131072: 'X_Button_1', 
                    65536: 'X_Button_2'}       

        self.DeviceEvent = namedtuple('DeviceEvent', ['inputDevice', 'event_type', 'key_code', 'x', 'y', 'scan_code', 'key_down'])
        self.DeviceEvent.__new__.__defaults__ = (None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
        
        self.default_key = "Value not defined"
        
    def key_event(self, event):
        while not self.signal.empty():
            self.signal_handler(self.signal.get())

        for listener_name, listener_queue in self.listener_queues.items():
            listener_queue.put(event)
            
    def key_down(self, event_type, key_code):
        key = str(key_code)

        if key not in self._key_down and event_type == 'key_down':
            self._key_down.add(key)
            return True
        
        elif key in self._key_down and event_type == 'key_up':
            self._key_down.remove(key)
            return True
        
    def if_block(self, event):
        for if_handler in self.if_handlers:
            result = if_handler(event)
            if result is not None and not result:
                return False
        return True

    def keyboard_low_level_handler(self, nCode, wParam, lParam):
        lParam = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)).contents.value
        
        rezult = self.key_down(self.event_types[wParam], lParam)
        event = self.DeviceEvent('Keyboard', self.event_types[wParam], lParam, key_down=self._key_down)
        
        if rezult: # !!! - Отсекаем повторяющийся ивент key_down
            self.key_event(event)
        
        if self.if_block(event):   
            return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(self.keyboard_hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        else:
            return -1
               
    def mouse_low_level_handler(self, nCode, wParam, lParam):
        point = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long * 2)).contents
        
        x = point[0]
        y = point[1]
        
        castomParam = self.mouse_key.get(lParam[1], self.default_key) if lParam[1] is not None else self.mouse_key[wParam]
        self.key_down(self.mouse_types[wParam], castomParam)
        
        event = self.DeviceEvent('Mouse', self.mouse_types[wParam], castomParam, x, y, lParam[1], self._key_down)
        self.key_event(event)
        
        if self.if_block(event):   
            return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(self.mouse_hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        else:
            return -1
    
    def listen(self):
        CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (
            ctypes.c_int,
            CMPFUNC,
            ctypes.c_void_p,
            ctypes.c_uint
        )

        keyboard_pointer = CMPFUNC(self.keyboard_low_level_handler)
        self.keyboard_hook_id = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboard_pointer,
                                                                       win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

        mouse_pointer = CMPFUNC(self.mouse_low_level_handler)
        self.mouse_hook_id = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL, mouse_pointer,
                                                                    win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

        atexit.register(ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, self.keyboard_hook_id)
        atexit.register(ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, self.mouse_hook_id)

        win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        print(f"Hooks завершил свою работу..")
            
    def add_if_handler(self, func): # Регестрируем колбэк-фильтров
        self.if_handlers.add(func) 
            
    def add_handler(self, func): # Регестрируем колбэк-обработчиков
        self.handlers.add(func) 
        
    def remove_if_handler(self, func): # Удаление колбэк-фильтров
        self.if_handlers.discard(func) 
            
    def remove_handler(self, func): # Удаление колбэк-обработчиков
        self.handlers.discard(func) 
        
    def create_listener_queues(self):
        self.listener_queues = {func.__name__: queue.Queue() for func in self.handlers}
     
    def create_listener(self):        
        self.listeners = [
        threading.Thread(target=self.wrapper, args=(self.listener_queues[func.__name__], func), name=func.__name__)
        for func in self.handlers
    ]
        
    def start_listener(self):
        for listener_thread in self.listeners:
            listener_thread.daemon = True
            listener_thread.start()
      
    def wrapper(self, listener_queue, func):
        while True:
            event = listener_queue.get()
            if event is None:
                break
            func(event) 
            
        print(f"Демон {func.__name__} завершил свою работу..")
            
    def start(self, use_daemon = False):
        self.create_listener_queues()
        self.create_listener()
        self.start_listener()
        
        self.flagRun=True
        # Создаем новый поток и передаем в него функцию self.listen() - без скобок! 
        # Мы передаем саму функцию в качестве объекта. В этом случае, функция не вызывается немедленно.
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.listen, name="Hooks")
        thread.daemon = use_daemon # Включить при использовании GUI 
        thread.start() # Запускаем Hooks в отдельном потоке
        self.thread_id = thread.native_id # Получаем дескриптор потока, используя атрибут native_id объекта threading.Thread
   
    def stop(self): # Останавливаем слушатели\хуки
        for listener_name, listener_queue in self.listener_queues.items():
            listener_queue.put(None)
        
        self.flagRun=False
        ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(self.keyboard_hook_id)
        ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(self.mouse_hook_id)
        
        self.listener_queues.clear()
        self.listeners.clear()
        self._key_down.clear()
        
        user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
        WM_QUIT = 0x0012
        user32.PostThreadMessageW(self.thread_id, WM_QUIT, 0, 0) # Используя дискриптор потока, отправляем сообщение WM_QUIT 
                                                            # Для остановки win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)    

    def hot_removal_handler(self, func): # Горячее удаление колбэк-обработчиков
        signal = {"hot_removal_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)
    
    def hot_plugging_handler(self, func):# Горячая регестрирация колбэк-обработчиков
        signal = {"hot_plugging_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)
    
    def hot_removal_if_handler(self, func): # Горячее удаление колбэк-фильтров
        signal = {"hot_removal_if_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)
    
    def hot_plugging_if_handler(self, func): # Горячая регестрирация колбэк-фильтров
        signal = {"hot_plugging_if_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)

    def signal_handler(self, handler_dict):
        match handler_dict:
            case {"hot_removal_handler": func}:
                
                self.handlers.discard(func) 
                stop_signal_queue = self.listener_queues.get(func.__name__)
                stop_signal_queue.put(None)
                self.listener_queues.pop(func.__name__, None)
                print(f"Handling hot removal for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case {"hot_plugging_handler": func}:
                
                self.handlers.add(func) 
                self.listener_queues.update({func.__name__: queue.Queue()})
                listener_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.wrapper, args=(self.listener_queues[func.__name__], func), name=func.__name__)
                self.listeners.append(listener_thread)
                listener_thread.daemon = True
                listener_thread.start()
                print(f"Handling hot plugging for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case {"hot_removal_if_handler": func}:
                
                self.if_handlers.discard(func) 
                print(f"Handling conditional hot removal for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case {"hot_plugging_if_handler": func}:
                
                self.if_handlers.add(func) 
                print(f"Handling conditional hot plugging for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case _:
                print("Unknown case")
                
    def get_if_handlers(self, objekt=None):
        if objekt == "__name__":
            return set(if_handler.__name__ for if_handler in self.if_handlers)
        else:
             return self.if_handlers

    def get_handlers(self, objekt=None):
        if objekt == "__name__":
            return set(handler.__name__ for handler in self.handlers)
        else:
             return self.handlers

    def get_status_hooks(self):
        return self.flagRun

if __name__ == '__main__':

    log = True
    def print_event(event):

        if log:
            print(f"!-----------: \n"
                  f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} -> {event.inputDevice} -> {event.event_type} -> {event.key_code}\n"
                  f"X: {event.x}, Y: {event.y}, Scan_code: {event.scan_code}\n"
                  f"____________! \n")   
            
    def print_event2(event):

        if log: 
            print(f"!-----------: \n"
                  f"Нажатые кнопки: {event.key_down}\n"
                  f"____________! \n")
                
    def print_event3(event):     
        if log:   
            threads = threading.enumerate()
            thread_names = [thread.name for thread in threads]
            threads_str = ', '.join(thread_names)
            print(f"!-----------: \n"
                  f"Активные потоки: {threads_str}\n"
                  f"____________! \n") 
            
    def _if_block(event):     
        if event.key_code == 49:   
            print(f"Блокируем кнопку клавиатуры [1]")
            return False
            
    def _if2_block(event):     
        if event.key_code == "left":   
            print(f"Блокируем кнопку мыши [left]")
            return False

    def _if3_block(event):     
    # Проверка условия ограничения координат мыши
        if event.inputDevice == "Mouse" and 0 <= event.y <= 250:
            # Блокировка движения мыши
            win32api.SetCursorPos((event.x, 250))
            return False  # Блокировать обработку события мыши 

        if event.inputDevice == "Mouse" and 1000 <= event.y <= 1080:
            win32api.SetCursorPos((event.x, 1000))
            return False

    input_listener = InputListener()
    
    input_listener.add_handler(print_event)
    input_listener.add_handler(print_event2)
    input_listener.add_handler(print_event3)
    
    input_listener.add_if_handler(_if_block)
    input_listener.add_if_handler(_if2_block)
    input_listener.add_if_handler(_if3_block)
    
    input_listener.start()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    input_listener.stop()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    input_listener.remove_handler(print_event2) # Удаление колбэк-обработчика на холодную
    input_listener.remove_if_handler(_if3_block)
    
    input_listener.start()
    
    time.sleep(5)

    input_listener.hot_removal_if_handler(_if_block)
    input_listener.hot_removal_if_handler(_if2_block)
    
    input_listener.hot_plugging_if_handler(_if3_block)
    
    input_listener.hot_removal_handler(print_event)
    
    print(input_listener.get_handlers("__name__"))
    print(input_listener.get_handlers())
    
    print(input_listener.get_if_handlers("__name__"))
    print(input_listener.get_if_handlers())
    
    input_listener.hot_plugging_handler(print_event2)
    input_listener.hot_removal_handler(print_event2)
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    input_listener.hot_plugging_handler(print_event)
    input_listener.hot_plugging_handler(print_event2)
    input_listener.hot_removal_if_handler(_if3_block)
```

Comment: Не З. Ы., а P. S.

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить "Low Level Hook" и при перехвате event просто его заблокировать! Вот простой пример: при нажатии клавиши "1" ни одна из программ не обработает этого нажатия. Не знаю насколько корректно так блокировать кнопки, но это работает.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import ctypes
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui
import atexit

KeyboardEvent = namedtuple('KeyboardEvent', ['event_type', 'key_code',
                                             'scan_code', 'alt_pressed',
                                             'time'])

handlers = []

def listen():
    
    def low_level_handler(nCode, wParam, lParam):
        event = KeyboardEvent(event_types[wParam], lParam[0], lParam[1],
                              lParam[2] == 32, lParam[3])
        
        if event.key_code == 8589934641:  # Код клавиши 1
            print("test")
            return -1  # Блокировать обработку сообщения

        for handler in handlers:
            handler(event)

        return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)

    event_types = {win32con.WM_KEYDOWN: 'key down',
                   win32con.WM_KEYUP: 'key up',
                   0x104: 'key down',  # WM_SYSKEYDOWN, used for Alt key.
                   0x105: 'key up',  # WM_SYSKEYUP, used for Alt key.
                   }

    CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (
        ctypes.c_int,
        CMPFUNC,
        ctypes.c_void_p,
        ctypes.c_uint
    )
    pointer = CMPFUNC(low_level_handler)

    hook_id = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, pointer,
                                                     win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

    atexit.register(ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, hook_id)

    while True:
        msg = win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        win32gui.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
        win32gui.DispatchMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def print_event(event):
        print("Event:", event)
        print("key_code:", hex(event.key_code))

    handlers.append(print_event)
    listen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Также используя "Low Level Hook", можно заблокировать и мышку. При этом обратите внимание, можно отключить обработку не только клавиш, но и ограничить область перемещения курсора. Насколько это корректный способ, я не знаю, но он работает.

Данный код заблокирует нажатия ПКМ на мышке и не одна из программ его не обработает. Также вы не сможете опустить или поднять курсор до границы экрана - упретесь в невидимую границу.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import ctypes
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui
import atexit

MouseEvent = namedtuple('MouseEvent', ['event_type', 'x', 'y'])

handlers = []

def listen():
    def low_level_handler(nCode, wParam, lParam):
        point = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long * 2)).contents
        x = point[0]
        y = point[1]
        event = MouseEvent(wParam, x, y)

        for handler in handlers:
            handler(event)
        
        # Проверка условия ограничения координат мыши
        if 0 <= y <= 250:
            # Блокировка движения мыши
            win32api.SetCursorPos((x, 250))
            return -1  # Блокировать обработку события мыши 

        if 1000 <= y <= 1080:
            
            win32api.SetCursorPos((x, 1000))
            return -1  # Блокировать обработку события мыши

        if event.event_type == win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP or event.event_type == win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Правая кнопка мыши сломалась..")
            return -1  # Блокировать обработку сообщения
        
        return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)

    CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (
        ctypes.c_int,
        CMPFUNC,
        ctypes.c_void_p,
        ctypes.c_uint
    )
    pointer = CMPFUNC(low_level_handler)

    hook_id = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL, pointer,
                                                     win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

    atexit.register(ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, hook_id)

    while True:
        msg = win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        win32gui.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
        win32gui.DispatchMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def print_event(event):
        print(f"Event Type: {event.event_type}")
        print(f"Position: ({event.x}, {event.y})")
        print()

    handlers.append(print_event)
    listen()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Нет проблем, немного дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: А в Линукс можно?  Хочу кнопку "режим кошки" когда кошка ложится на клавиатуру - та блокируется

Comment: В Linux нет аналога функций win32api, win32gui и т.д., поскольку они предназначены специально для Windows.

Для работы с мышью и клавиатурой в Linux нужно будет использовать другой способ. Один из способов сделать это - использовать библиотеку Xlib, которая предоставляет интерфейс для работы с X-сервером (графическая подсистема в большинстве дистрибутивов Linux).

Чисто технически, можно реализовать решение и для Линукс, но текущий код придётся полностью переписать.  И я бы вам даже помог, но у меня нету Линукса))